# is there a way I can get the IP Address when I connect to a VPN server

Tags: powershell, ip-address, powershell-2.0, vpn

I am currently using Powershell to get me the list of all the IP Address of my machine. When I am not using my vpn connection ( when I am at work) I get the IP Address of my machine correct. but When I am at home and I am using my VPN connection, I get another IP Address which is being provided by the client. I would like to get the second IP Address provided to me by the VPN client.

I am currently using this query

> (gwmi -query "Select IPAddress From Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration = True").IpAddress

However like I have said before this query does not give me the IP address provided by the VPN client .

Please suggest..

Thanks and Regards
Nav

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry($a).addresslist
```

Return al IP4 and IP6.
Cisco VPN not always show to client the IP of vpn connection.

Comment: Thanks .. I marked your answer as thr right asnwer.. There was one more Information that I wish to seek... How can I only get the IP Address from the list.. Right now its returning a lot of properties.. which i would not use in normal case.. I am only interested in the IP part .. thanks

Comment: Thanks... I got it.. 
IPAddressToString resolves the issue.. thanks :)

Comment: [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry($a).addresslist[index].ipaddresstostring #wehre [index] is the HostEntry that you search for.